# To calculate a derivative of a set of points, is it more correct to interpolate finite differences or to derivate the interpolation?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods, partial-derivative

I have a series of points extracted from numerical simulations. I also recently discovered the amazing power of finite differences. Nevertheless, I was used to estimate my derivatives from the analytic expression of the interpolation between my points.

My question: Is it better, in the sense *more correct*:

1. to calculate numerically the partial derivatives using finite differences and then interpolating them,
2. or to interpolate my points and derivate analytically the interpolation?

I feel like way 1 is better for my sets. I also imagine that interpolation or trend curves may have non-physical variations, *e.g.* [Runge oscillations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) in the case of polynomial interpolation. Such oscillations would lead way 2 to being completely non-sense.

Of course I did extensive testings on my sets of points, but I'd like a more rigorous answer than I'm able to give.

Comment: I am not sure what interpolation methods and finite difference methods you are focusing on. Finite difference methods usually coincide with the result from some interpolation methods but require less computation.